# java 2d puzzle application, cannot draw more then one piece

Tags: java, graphics, 2d

i'm trying to write a jigsaw puzzle application where an image is cut in pieces, scrambled, and the user have to rearrange them with drag&drop to reassemble the original image. (something like this: http://www.jigzone.com/puzzles/74055D549FF0?z=5). 
i have to write this in java with Graphics2d.

so, at first i'm trying to make some kind of component which can show a part of the image (a rectangle for now), and can be dragged with mouse.

the code below works well when there is only one one such component. the problem is, when i add the second component, the first one is no longer visible.

i'm really stuck here. i have a feeling i'm missing something really basic. or maybe i'm on a wrong way. any help will be greatly appreciated.

edit: i changed a bit the code according to suggestions, however, still not working as expected.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.MouseInputAdapter;

public class GraphicDragAndDrop extends JPanel {
    Rectangle rect;
    Image img;

    public GraphicDragAndDrop(String imgFile, int x0, int y0){
        rect = new Rectangle(x0, y0, 150, 75);
        img = new ImageIcon(imgFile).getImage();
    }


    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.setClip(rect);
        int x = rect.x;
        int y = rect.y;
        g2d.drawImage(img, x, y, this);
    }

    public void setRect(int x, int y) {
        rect.setLocation(x, y);
        repaint();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // first piece
        GraphicDragAndDrop piece1 = new GraphicDragAndDrop("a.png", 0, 0);
        piece1.setRect(0, 0);
        new GraphicDragController(piece1);

        // second piece --> only this will be visible
        GraphicDragAndDrop piece2 = new GraphicDragAndDrop("a.png", 200, 200);
        //GraphicDragAndDrop piece2 = new GraphicDragAndDrop("b.png", 200, 200); // does'n work either
        piece2.setRect(150, 150);
        new GraphicDragController(piece2);

        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.add(piece1);
        f.add(piece2);
        f.setSize(500,500);
        f.setLocation(300,100);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}

class GraphicDragController extends MouseInputAdapter {
    GraphicDragAndDrop component;
    Point offset = new Point();
    boolean dragging = false;

    public GraphicDragController(GraphicDragAndDrop gdad) {
        component = gdad;
        component.addMouseListener(this);
        component.addMouseMotionListener(this);
    }

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        Point p = e.getPoint();
        Rectangle r = component.rect;
        if(r.contains(p)) {
            offset.x = p.x - r.x;
            offset.y = p.y - r.y;
            dragging = true;
        }
    }

    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        dragging = false;
    }

    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
        if(dragging) {
            int x = e.getX() - offset.x;
            int y = e.getY() - offset.y;
            component.setRect(x, y);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code above is written to draw only one image:

```
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);

    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2d.setClip(rect);
    int x = rect.x;
    int y = rect.y;

    // here
    g2d.drawImage(new ImageIcon("a.png").getImage(), x, y, this);
}
```

- If you need to draw more than one image, then consider creating a **collection** of images and iterating through the collection in paintComponent using a for loop:
- also, **never** read in the image from within paintComponent since this method should be lean, mean and fast, and should concern itself with painting only. Also, there's no need to read the image in each time your program has to draw it as that's very inefficient and will slow the program unnecessarily. Instead read the image in *once* in the constructor or a similar init method.

For example,

```
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);

    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

    for (Image img: myImageCollection) {
       g2d.drawImage(img, 0, 0, this);
    }
}
```

---

**Edit**
You state:

> also, my plan was to have more objects of GraphicDragAndDrop class, each of them showing a different piece of the original image. is my approach wrong?

You could use components, but I have a feeling that it would be easy to drag images. I think it would be easier to rotate them for instance if you want your program to have this functionality. If not, though then sure use a component, but if you go this route, I would recommend using a JLabel and simply setting its ImageIcon rather than dragging JPanels.

Comment: thank you for your answer. having new ImageIcon(...) in paintComponent isn't a good idea of course, but it isn't related to my problem. also, my plan was to have more objects of GraphicDragAndDrop class, each of them showing a different piece of the original image. is my approach wrong?

Comment: Hove, thank you very much! i followed you suggestions and my project is almost done.

Comment: @Luc: glad your project is moving forward!